# Can the semi-characteristic function of $\{x \mid \varphi_x(x)\downarrow\}$ be extended to a total function?

Tags: computability

The semi-characteristic function of $K = \{x \mid \varphi_x(x)\downarrow\}$, that is the set of all indices $x$ such that the $x$-th computable function converges on the input $x$, is the following:

$$ \chi'_K(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in K \\ \text{undefined} & \text{o.w.} \end{cases} $$

This partial function is computable. A colleague of mine claimed that it can be extended to a total function, and the professor, whom had initially claimed this was not the case, agreed, and changed the example.

I can't currently see a way of extending it though, because by substituting any value to the undefined I'd end up with a non-computable function... Is there a way?

Comment: You can extend it the the computable function that is always $1$. That's not particularly useful, but it does extend $\chi_K'$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Ah, that's true! This way there is no need to make the choice! Thank you